# Do too many redirects hurt the SEO structure of Wordpress blog?

Tags: seo, wordpress, redirects

I have a website http://www.voiceable.org/ and just moved a category posts to the subdomain http://tech-fun.voiceable.org/ Now, i am using redirection plugin for 301 redirection from that category to sub domain. The category has more then 500 posts, is it safe to use these no of 301 redirection from SEO point of view or will it have any impact on search engine ranking?

Comment: Hi Voiceable, this question is not specific to WordPress and should be on prowebmaster.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with moving pages from the main domain to a sub-domain is that it is painless when correct redirects are in place.

I have only lost rankings when trying to move documents from one domain to a completely different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is perfectly fine, that is was 301's are made for :)

Comment: Google doesn't favor mass redirect though, and its impossible to know if transferring content of the main domain to sub domain will be negative or positive. 301's are good for redirecting a couple of pages but mass redirecting can damage rankings some juice is lost.